# What's the plural of quantum?

Tags: grammatical-number

As in a number of the smallest de facto units of anything you can have in the universe?

Currently in the running in my mind:

- Quanta
- Quantums

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/quantum), [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/quantum), The American Heritage Dictionary of the English Language, and the Collins English Dictionary all list only *quanta* as the plural form. So if I wanted to be on the safe side, I'd recommend that over *quantums*. The usage stats from the [British National Corpus](http://www.natcorp.ox.ac.uk/) and the [Corpus of Contemporary American English](http://www.americancorpus.org) look as follows:

```
         BNC   COCA

quanta    35     95
quantums   0      3
```

Google results are too skewed to be included, as Quanta seems to be a popular proper name.

Comment: Quantum is a derivation from Latin, and thus takes the Latin pluralisation. Quantum->Quanta like Forum->Fora and so forth.

Answer (score 4):

'Quanta' is usually used, but 'quantums' is also valid according to the *Oxford English Dictionary*.

Comment: In physics, *quanta* would be the usual plural. However, students also use *Quantum* also to mean their class on Quantum Mechanics, and if you somehow needed to pluralize that (I don't see how that would happen), the plural would be *Quantums*.

Comment: Wow, @Peter Shor, straight from the horse's mouth. :)